# Why is mitzvah 611 not in The Six Constant Mitzvot?

Tags: mitzvah, derech-eretz-manners, sefer-hachinuch

[Mitzvah 611](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.611?lang=bi) according to the Sefer HaChinuch is to walk in HaShem's ways. Sefaria writes:

"The commandment to walk in - and make oneself similar through - the ways of God, may He be blessed:"

Later down, it is [written](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.611.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

"And this commandment is practiced in every place and at all times by males and females. And one who transgresses it and does not make efforts to straighten his ways, to conquer his impulse, to improve his thoughts and deeds for the Love of God and to fulfill this commandment, has violated this positive commandment.
"

So, why is this not a Constant Mitzvah, if the Chinuch clearly writes it is practiced at all times, similar language he uses to describe other Mitzvot that ARE considered constant?

Comment: Hi Mordechai and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Hope to see you around.

Comment: The phrase you seem to be referring to (בכל מקום ובכל זמן) just means that the mitzvah is not limited to a certain time period or location.  For instance, tefillin is described with the same phrase, even though it is not a constant mitzvah.

Comment: @Alex so what is the difference between those (tefillin, 611, etc.) and the Six Constant?